# Array of array?

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to model a cake in blender, specifically, the "string of pearls" on a wedding cake. The curved line of pearls in this image:

[image: Example cake]

Using an array modifier and a few curve deforms, I have been able to create a single strand of pearls. The process I followed is this:

1. Create a sphere for the pearl
2. Create a bezier circle of the radius of the loop (Circle A)
3. Create a bezier circle of the radius of the cake (Circle B)
4. Give the pearl an array modifier and parent it to Circle A with a curve deformer.
5. Parent the pearl to Circle B with another curve deformer.

That gives me this: 
[image: Progress so far]

Now if I try to add another array modifier, to the pearls, I get a new set of pearls above the cake and can't find a way to reposition it, or get them to follow the cake. If I add an array modifier to Circle B and parent it to Circle A, I get the circle going around the cake, but no pearls.

How can I duplicate this "loop" around the cake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can succeed with your method, I would do it with a simpler way:

- Create a circle arc, duplicate it in *Edit* mode, join the duplications, in *Object* mode apply the rotation, make it circular with a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode, *Angle* 360°), apply the modifier and join the first and last vertices. You could have given your curve a *Curve* modifier instead, with a circle as *Curve*, maybe it's something you'd have prefered but the *Simple Deform* is easier in my opinion.

[image]

- Make the curve snap to the surface of your cake.

[image]

- Put the origin of the curve on one of its vertices, put the pearl on the exact same point, give your pearl an *Array* modifier.

[image]

- With this method the pearls are deformed and it's particularly visible if the curve angle is too narrow. If you want to avoid that you could use *Instancing*: Don't use any modifiers, convert the curve to mesh, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Instancing*, click *Verts*, then parent the pearl to the curve (which is now a mesh), the pearl should appear on each vertex of the curve.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! This looks like exactly what I need. One deviation I made was at the beginning instead of duplicating the curve, I used an array modifier linked to another curve around the cake, then converted it to a mesh (required to apply the modifier), joined the pieces, then converted back to a curve. This let me fine tune the scaling and positioning before duplicating..

Comment: So, I am getting stuck on the final step, `Put the origin of the curve on one of its vertices, put the pearl on the exact same point, give your pearl an Array modifier.` How do I do this? I don't see an option to move the origin in edit mode, and I am not sure how I am linking the objects once I put the pearl in the same spot, am I just parenting it?

Comment: Select the curve vertex where you want the origin to be, press shift S > Cursor To Selected, then back in Object mode, go in the header menu > Object > Set Origin > Origin To 3D Cursor, then stay in Object mode, keep the 3D cursor where it is, select the pearl and again shift S > Selection To Cursor

Comment: Ok, so I now have the pearl sitting on the vertex of the curve. How do I tell the pearl to follow the curve? Do I parent it? Parent it with curve deform? That is what I tried, but the pearls end up getting misshappen, especially at the peaks. I also tried leaving it unparented and setting it to use the curve as an offset. That was apparently wrong as well.

Comment: Yes with this method the pearls are deformed and it's particularly visible if the curve angle is too narrow. What you can do is keep a copy of the whole thing, then apply the modifiers, delete the deformed pearls and put some good ones at the same position. You could also use another method: Don't use any modifiers, convert the curve to mesh, go in the Properties panel > Object > Instancing, click Verts, then parent the pearl to the curve (which is now a mesh), the pearl should appear on each vertex of the curve.